# NDK project build with multiple CMakeFiles.txt

Tags: gradle, cmake, android-ndk

My intent is to have prebuilt libprebuilt.so and libmylib.so built into the apk. My project is structured like this

```
    |-mylib_prebuilts
    |  |-libprebuilt.so
    |  |-include_dir
    |  '-CMakeFiles.txt
    |-mylib
    |  |-src
    |  '-CMakeFiles.txt
    '-build.gradle
```

In the CMakeFiles.txt for mylib_prebuilts, I have the following.

```
add_library(prebuiltlib SHARED IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(prebuiltlib INTERFACE include_dir)
set_property(TARGET prebuiltlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION libprebuilt.so)
```

In the CMakeFiles.txt for lib, I have the following

```
add_subdirectory(../mylib_prebuilts mylib_prebuilts)
add_library(mylib SHARED ${srcs})
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC prebuiltlib)
```

The root gradle.build has the following

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        version '3.18.1'
        path 'mylib/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

I cannot reach the prebuilt headers or library from mylib. I get "headers not found" error, or if I manually add the header path using `include_directories(../mylib_prebuilts/include_dir)`, build cannot find symbols when linking.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with a solution I stumbled upon.

mylib_prebuilts/CMakeLists.txt has to contain the following changes.

1. Add `GLOBAL` keyword to add_library call.
2. Use absolute path instead
   of relative for set_property call using `${MAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`
   variable

```
add_library(prebuiltlib SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
target_include_directories(prebuiltlib INTERFACE include_dir)
set_property(TARGET prebuiltlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libprebuilt.so)
```